# problema para publicar un valor en un input t= text con un ID

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo una duda. He buscado en la web pero, no he podido encontrar cómo se hace.

estoy viendo un sistema ya creado, pero quiero modificar algunas cosas.

Tengo una pagina Ingreso.php con un código que me trae los valores de la base de datos.

```
$siniestro[] = array("cod_ref"=>$row[0],"ramo"=>$row[1],"fecha"=>htmlentities($row[2]), etc, etc, etc);
$this->respuesta=$siniestro;
return  $this->respuesta;
```

el cual me da un return de respuesta.

bueno lo leo con esto:

```
$.getJSON("siniestro.php",{x:x},function(detalleFT){
  $.each(detalleFT[0], function(key,valor){ 
    $("#"+key).html(valor);
  });
});
```

con esto obtengo los valores de mi pagina siniestro mediante ID, los cuales quiero mostrarlos en input="text" , pero los input text aparecen vacios, no asi si los vuelco en un  por ejemplo, pero lo que me interesa es hacer esos campos editables en el input text pero con el valor ya cargado de los ID.

no sé si queda muy clara mi explicacion.

tal vez los estoy recogiendo mal por ID, o si sería más facil pasarlo a variables php, no sé, necesito ayuda en este tema, me veo un poco atascado.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, debes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
$("#"+key).val(valor);
```

Answer (score -1):

La función de jquery `.html()` no te sirve para este caso.
En tu caso seria algo como:

```
//linea de codigo donde colocas tu dato
$("#"+key).attr( "atributo", valor );
```

Esto suponiendo que ya está el campo `<input>` creado

Comment: No entiendo cómo cambiar el atributo `"atributo"` lograría que muestre ese valor en el input.

Comment: en `atributo` colocas `value`, así se mostrará en el campo el valor que quieres mostrar.

Comment: ¿No crees que sería una respuesta más acertada si efectivamente lograra mostrar el valor en el input, tal cual lo quiere el autor?